# How to dual boot 11.04 and Win 7 on seperate drives

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

So I have Ubuntu 11.04 on 1TB HDD and Win 7 on another 1TB HDD.  Right now I have to unplug a SATA cable to get to boot into one or the other.  What is the best way to be able to pick.  I don't care which OS I do it in or which is the primary, if there has to be one.  I have an MSI mobo.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the boot menu provided by your motherboard. At the bios screen you can press a button to get to the boot menu, this is often F10 or F12 but it varies between models and manufacturers.

At the boot menu select the drive you want to boot from and it will boot the os on that drive.

This is a quite simple solution and it gives a good separation between the systems.

If you don't want to go with the bios boot menu you can find a comprehensive guide over at [linuxbsdos.com](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/22/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-11-04/) that describes how to install ubuntu 11.04 and configure a dual boot with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Going into the BIOS and changing your boot sequence every time you want to switch between operating systems is not the best solution. One option would be to install Ubuntu within windows using wubi.

If you're installing the operating systems on separate drives, however, you should install windows first because windows may disable other bootloaders during its installation. Once you're done installing windows, install Ubuntu on a separate partition/drive. Ubuntu should detect windows and add it to the boot menu for dual booting automatically. This works for me and should for you.

Lastly, why do you have to unplug one of your drives to boot from the other? I'm guessing you disconnected the drive containing windows during the ubuntu install so it might not have detected and added windows to the boot menu. Or it may just be ubuntu's fault. Either way, I would suggest reinstalling ubuntu so you have a properly configured dual boot system and not one where you have to edit bios settings to switch operating systems.